# why my curve fitting plot using matplotlib looks obscured?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use the polyfit function for curve fitting. The noisy data is generated using 3rd order polynomial and am using the 3rd degree when calling polyfit function. But the resulting plot doesn't have any element of curve in it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

noise_scale = 100
number_of_samples = 100
x = 25*(np.random.rand(number_of_samples,1)-0.8)
y = 5*x+20*x**2+1*x**3 + noise_scale*np.random.randn(number_of_samples,1)
xs = x.flatten()
ys = y.flatten()

p3 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xs, ys, 3))
plt.plot(xs,ys,'b.',xs, p3(xs),'r--')
```

[image]

I would like to know what am doing wrong here.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plt.plot()` plots points in the order their coordinates appear in the `xs` and `ys` arrays and connects successive points by straight line segments. Since numbers in the `xs` array are in a random order, these straight line segments zigzag back and forth as the values of `xs` increase and decrease. In order to get a plot of a polynomial function, the array `xs` needs to be sorted from the smallest value to the largest. The array `ys` needs to be sorted accordingly so that the y-coordinates of points still correspond to their associated x-coordinates. This can be done as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

noise_scale = 100
number_of_samples = 100
x = 25*(np.random.rand(number_of_samples,1)-0.8)
y = 5*x+20*x**2+1*x**3 + noise_scale*np.random.randn(number_of_samples,1)
xs = x.flatten()
ys = y.flatten()

# sort coordinates
s = np.argsort(xs)
xs = xs[s]
ys = ys[s]

p3 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xs, ys, 3))
plt.plot(xs,ys,'b.',xs, p3(xs),'r--')
```

This gives:

[image: curve fitting]

Comment: thank you.  it will be great, if you could explain, why the sorting is needed ?